# how to include bashprofile from jenkins?

Tags: bash, jenkins, server, jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on restarting Tomcat from remote server. I can able to connect to server and view the output of few basic commands. When i'm performing tomcat/apache restart its not happening since some configurations defined in bashrc. How to include bash from my jenkins? These are my lines

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -tt uname@ip
cd tomcat/bindirectory
catalina.sh stop
sleep 4
catalina.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins by default uses non-interactive logins.

`.bahsrc` is executed.

`/etc/profile` , `/etc/default/*` are not.

I'm not entirely sure on what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe add some output as well.